# How to add compiled javascript library to typescript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I have an Typescript project (ProjectA) that uses few nodes packages. Aside I have babel project (ProjectB) which build configuration supports output for multiple module definition standards: amd, common.js, esm.

Is it possible to incorporate compiled ProjectB into ProjectA?

So far inside ProjectA i have created folder for ProjectB-dist, and placed there all of the outputs of ProjectB.

Inside one of the .ts files I have tried to import ProjectB as:

```
import ProjectB form './ProjectB-dist/output.common.js'
```

I have placed types for this project inside my @types folder. But compiler complains:

*Could not find a declaration file for module './ProjectB-dist/output.common.js'.*

Maybe I'm missing something with module concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import a library, just use the path to it (without the .js extension): `import "./ProjectB-dist/output.common"`. If after doing this the compiler still complains about a declaration file, then create that file named **output.common.d.ts** in a directory and put the following into it: 
`declare module "./ProjectB-dist/output.common";`